# Relative URLs, URL Rewriting, and Virtual Directories -- oh my!

Tags: asp.net, iis

We're currently using a shared host to save on cost. We have our public website and our SaaS product hosted under virtual directories (/app and /public) on our shared host. We give vanity subdomains to our clients (i.e. client1.myproduct.com) so we have a couple of rewrite rules to make everything work correctly.

Kind of irrelvant to the actual issue, but how we've set it up is if the HTTP_HOST parameter does not start with www and if the subdomain is not empty then we redirect to /app, otherwise we show whatever is in the root.

However, problems arise with relative URLs. For instance,

```
~/Scripts/jQuery.js
```

resolves to

```
/app/Scripts/jQuery.js
```

but thanks to the rewrite rules you actually navigate to the script via

```
/Scripts/jQuery.js
```

Obviously I can change all URLs to be absolute (i.e. `/Scripts/jQuery.js` instead of `~/Scripts/jQuery.js`) but that is suboptimal for obvious reasons.

It looks like functions like `ResolveUrl` use `TemplateSourceDirectory` to resolve relative URLs. Is it possible to overwrite it's value somewhere? Is there a better way of handling this that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't get it: the rewrite rule are good or wrong? Why don't change the rewrite rule if it is pointing to a bad url?

Answer (score 1):

Brad,

It's a bit hard to answer without knowing what you are using to rewrite your URLs. In the past people had a tendency to use something defined in their application's web.config, which processed way past the early ISAPI driver actions.

For example, Helicon's ISAPIRewrite happens very early on while IIS7's more recent URL Rewrite occurs a bit later in processing.

It would also help to see your actual rewrite rules including their conditions, regex pattern to match and the rewrite pattern to output.

That said, unless I'm oversimplifying this couldn't you simply detect when the URL is prefixed with the tilde "~" and strip it in an earlier rule. (Mark that rule to continue on to the remaining rules)

Then, when your next rule processed, it would do so with the relative URL pattern that started with a "/".

Let me know if I've missed something, and if so, provide the info I mention above.